# converting String YYYY-MM to Date YYYY-MM-DD

Tags: sql-server, string, date, datetime, type-conversion

I have a set of data below and they are all in string.

```
EndDate
--------
2017-04

2017-02
2017-01
2017-03

2017-06
```

I would like to add the last date of the month into it.

```
EndDate
--------
2017-04-30

2017-02-28
2017-01-31
2017-03-31

2017-06-30
```

I'm thinking to convert them to date first and use EOMONTH syntax to give the last date of the month. However I have tried to convert the data to date using `convert(datetime, EndDate)` and it fails.

I tried a the syntax below from a post in stackoverflow however it gives me error message as well.

```
EOMONTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),CAST(EndDate + '01' AS DATETIME),120))
```

FYI, the blank value should remain in the column.

I'm using SQL Server 2012

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: could you provied the error  ?

Comment: If you get an error, post it. What data types are the arguments into `EOMONTH`? It's not `VARCHAR(MAX)` thats for sure.  So why convert it?

Comment: zambonee got it right.

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. I think the blank value cause this error.

Comment: GOT IT. case when [EndDate] = '' then '' else EOMONTH(CONVERT(date, [EndDate] + '-01', 120)) end. THANKS ALL FOR YOUR HELP =D. PLUS 1 FOR ALL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close!

```
SELECT EOMONTH(TRY_CONVERT(date, EndDate + '-01', 120)) FROM ...
```

The date style 120 is yyyy-mm-dd, but you were creating a value that was yyyy-mmdd. Also, you were passing a varchar into `EOMONTH` when you should just give it a date parameter.

Comment: Plus1 - I would just suggest try_convert ... just in case of bogus or unexpected data

Comment: Hi Zambonee, thanks for your help. I still got the error message Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. I think the blank value doesn't like to be converted into date.

Comment: @AdhityaSanusi I just updated my answer to account for unexpected values.

Comment: To JohnCappelletti and Zambonee : yes, i prefer using try_convert as it will convert blank cell into NULL instead of using CASE where column is '' then '' and convert blank cell into 1900-01-01. Thanks a lot guys. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it :

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(EndDate, '') <> '' THEN EOMONTH(CAST(EndDate + '-01' AS DATETIME)) ELSE EndDate END
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I still have the same error message. Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.